# How to add Column vector to Data Frame (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df with `365 rows × 8 columns`.

[image]

Columns are the following `['tave', 'tmax', 'tmin', 'vp', 'rhmax', 'rhmin', 'pp', 'gust']` 
So there are 365 measures of `'tave'` during the year. 
I want to add new column called `'next day tave'` in the beginning of df.

***How to do it?***

My attempt is the following:

```
# let's add new column with "next day tave"
# "next day tave" is the value of next day
# e.g row 0, tave=-13.535, next tave=-5.791
 
next_tave_val = df.values[1:, 0:1]
print(next_tave_val.shape)
(364, 1)

# "next day tave" is 364 and we want to add that column to df that is 365 rows
# so need to add one more value to make it 365
# to append as 2d array

next_tave_val = np.append(next_tave_val, [[0]], axis=0)
print(next_tave_val.shape)

# now let's add 'next tave' column to df

df = df.insert(0,'next tave', next_tave_val)
print(df.shape)
```

Returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can look at the examples in the documentation of `df.insert` to see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a function designed for this very purpose: [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['next day tave'] = df['tave'].shift(1)
```